# Which C version introduced # stringizing and ## concatenation operators?

Tags: c

Which C version introduced `#` stringizing and `##` concatenation operators?
I could not find a reference for this.
I know `enum` was introduced in C89.

Comment: What the heck is "stringzing"?

Comment: They were added by the C89/C90 standard.  Both mechanisms were invented by the committee; there wasn't widespread prior art.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I trust you on this one. Independently, is there a reference somewhere about what features got standardized/added there and the history of how the committee made these sorts of calls? Could be a fun read.

Answer (score 3):

Both the `#` and `##` operators were added to the first C standard — the C89 (ANSI) or C90 (ISO) standard.  They were added by the committee because the prior art was inconsistent and would not have been easy to standardize (and wasn't consistent anyway).

You need to read §6.10.3.2 of the [Rationale for the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) where the `#` operator is discussed as an invention of the standard committee, and §6.10.3.3 where the `##` operator is discussed.  Officially, that's the C99 rationale, but it is an extension of the C90 rationale, and clearly documents when something was added in C99.  There isn't an equivalent C11 rationale document, sadly.

Comment: I had no idea this existed. Thanks so much for posting the link!

Answer (score 1):

The `#` and `##` operators were introduced ever since C89.

See C89 [3.8.3.2 The # operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.8.3.2) and [3.8.3.3 The ## operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.8.3.3).